# React js Socket.io and State

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, socket.io

Hello I am trying to save in a state the response that my socket sends me through the back end

This is a method where I send messages to my socket

```
export default class Home extends Component { 

    constructor(){
        super()

        this.state = {
          informationReceived: 'Nothing yet!'
        }
        const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
        const socket = io('http://localhost:8080', {
            query: { token: token }
        });

        socket.on('success', (receivedInfo) => {
            this.setState({
              informationReceived: receivedInfo
            })
          })

      }

      emitInfoToAll = () => {
        const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
        console.log('entrou')
        const socket = io('http://localhost:8080',{
            query: { token: token }
        });

        socket.emit('myevent', 'Hello realtime connected users!')
        console.log(this.state.informationReceived);
      }
}
```

But this way I would be opening connection to my socket twice when sending and receiving
I was wondering how I can only open one connection so when I send a reply to my backend I don't have to open again

and how could I set these values ​​that I get for my p's tags:

```
                <p> Name: <span className = "name"> </span> </p>
                <p> Points: <span className = "points"> 0 </span> </p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should place `socket` as state of the component so that you can mock it in `emitInfoToAll` method

```
export default class Home extends Component { 

constructor(){
    super()

    this.state = {
      informationReceived: 'Nothing yet!'
      socket: null;
    }

    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    socket = io('http://localhost:8080', {
        query: { token: token }
    });

    socket.on('success', (receivedInfo) => {
        this.setState({
          informationReceived: receivedInfo
        })
      })

  }

  emitInfoToAll = () => {
    const { socket } = this.state;
    console.log('entrou')
    socket.emit('myevent', 'Hello realtime connected users!')
    console.log(this.state.informationReceived);
  }
}
```

Update: Help set value to `p` tag

```
export default class Home extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super()

        this.state = {
            informationReceived: 'Nothing yet!',
            socket: null
        }

        const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
        socket = io('http://localhost:8080', {
            query: { token: token }
        });

        socket.on('success', (receivedInfo) => {
            this.setState({
                informationReceived: receivedInfo
            })
        })

    }

    emitInfoToAll = () => {
        const { socket } = this.state;
        console.log('entrou')
        socket.emit('myevent', 'Hello realtime connected users!')
        console.log(this.state.informationReceived);
    }

    render() {
        const { informationReceived } = this.state;
        const { name, point } = informationReceived;
        return (
            <div>
                <p> Name: <span className="name">{name}</span> </p>
                <p> Points: <span className="points">{point}</span> </p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks bro and how could I set these values ​​that I get for my p's tags:

                    <p>

Comment: @gabriel I already update the new code that help you set the downloaded values to p's tag. Please check and mark it as correct if it work. Thanks

Comment: thanks @ Hay Trần 
If I want every modification to my backend to present in my front end would I have to useEfect inside my constructor? Why so my value does not update even changing in the backend

Comment: Why don't you use `socket.on` to listen which data changed in backend?

Comment: it is better to use ```useMemo```
But in my opinion better use ```context``` and place your socket client there, then you can useContext or consumer to access your socket client anywhere.

Comment: Yes I use it inside my constructor, but it is not changing my state

Comment: @ Vahid Ali Mohamadi could you help me with an example? How would I do, I'm a little confused

Comment: @VahidAlimohamadi yeap, your suggestion is better. But in that case I just help him bypass the problem as soon as possible

Comment: now you can place your socket events in ```componentDidMount``` if u use react-hooks it is equal to useEffect but with empty array as second arg.

Comment: @gabriel The event in constructor you mention is `success` event, right?

Comment: Yes just a successful event to test

Comment: I'll take a look at componentDidMount
but basically i would have to put all my socket events where i get msg from my back end?

Comment: Have you tested your backend work properly? https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/socketio-tester/cgmimdpepcncnjgclhnhghdooepibakm

Comment: omg i was doing something wrong, now it worked, but what would it be like using context and componentDidMount
could you give me an example?

Comment: If it doesn't bother you I would be very grateful